# Display images using POHorizontalList dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using [POHorizontalList](https://github.com/polatolu/POHorizontalList). 
The sample code is using static number of images to be displayed. In my case the number of images that i need to display is based on the images from the server. I can display one image using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [mutableStorage count]; i++){
    NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strURL]]];

    ListItem *item1 = [[ListItem alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60) image:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata] text:nil];

    freeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: item1, nil];   
}
list = [[POHorizontalList alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 120.0) title:title items:freeList];
```

Lets say I have 3 images to display. How can I make my code display the 3 images.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hei Arianne Lee, you can try this code

```
[freelist addObject:item1];
```

instead of

```
freeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: item1, nil];
```

hope it will works :)